# Convert Jquery to javascript (find())

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an old school app. It's so old that it doesn't support jquery. Which is fine in most cases, but I've run into a spot where it is annoying the hell out of me.

I need to select a link with the word 'Novedades' in it so I can change around the http attribute. Wish I could do this a different way, but they have a CMS is changing everything every way I turn. :) Can you tell I love this system?

Normally, this is how I would write it in Jquery. Simple enough, but how can I turn the find into plain javascript?

```
var blog = $('.navbar-nav').find('a:contains(Novedades)');
```

So obviously this would start with

```
var blog = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-nav")
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Selecting based on text content is less than idea. However, if there's no other way, I'd just use `document.querySelectorAll()` with a single selector to get the `'.navbar-nav a'` elements, then filter them down by testing the `.textContent` of each element.

Comment: @squint Yeah, I don't like selecting text either, but this is an awful system. Not quite sure I know where you're going with that though. Something like document.querySelectorAll('navbar-nav a').textContent('Novedades') ?

Comment: Almost. The `querySelectorAll` method returns a collection. It sounds like you only need to perform a single operation, so the simplest, most broadly compatible way would be to use a `for` loop to iterate the collection, check the `.textContent` property of each individual element, and then change the `href` in the loop.

Comment: @zazvorniki you should manually create a function that loops through the `<a>` tags and checks its content. Like the link I posted earlier. that's one way to do it

Comment: If you're only supporting modern browsers, or can transpile the code, there's nicer syntax available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on squint's comment, you'll have to get old school and loop through them:

```
var blog = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav a");
for (var i=0;i<blog.length;i++){
   var thisBlog = blog[i];
   var txt = thisBlog.textContent.toLowerCase();
   if (txt.indexOf('novedades') > -1){
      //do your thing
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me, though it could be less verbose without those single-use variables. An in emulating `:contains()`, it should remain case sensitive. `if (blog[i].textContent.indexOf('Novedades') > -1){`

Comment: Gotcha, was being intentionally verbose for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me from banging my head against the desk!